# How to move the layout up when the software keyboard is shown in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I have a UITextField. The soft keyboard covers the UITextField when I click.
How can I move the layout up so I want it to show above the keyboard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

you can use https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

xamarin ios binding  https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager

Xamarin Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager/

Comment: Amazing -- phew glad they created this

Answer (score 1):

See a sample implimentation

Variables for the controller that houses the textboxes

```
private UIView activeview;             // Controller that activated the keyboard
private float scroll_amount = 0.0f;    // amount to scroll 
private float bottom = 0.0f;           // bottom point
private float offset = 10.0f;          // extra offset
private bool moveViewUp = false;           // which direction are we moving
```

Keyboard observers for ViewDidLoad().

```
// Keyboard popup
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver
(UIKeyboard.DidShowNotification,KeyBoardUpNotification);

// Keyboard Down
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver
(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification,KeyBoardDownNotification);
```

First up is the KeyboardUpNotification method.  Essentially you calculate if the control will be hidden by the keyboard and if so calculate how much the view needs to be moved to show the control, and then move it.

```
private void KeyBoardUpNotification(NSNotification notification)
{
    // get the keyboard size
    RectangleF r = UIKeyboard.BoundsFromNotification (notification);

    // Find what opened the keyboard
    foreach (UIView view in this.View.Subviews) {
        if (view.IsFirstResponder)
            activeview = view;
    }

    // Bottom of the controller = initial position + height + offset      
    bottom = (activeview.Frame.Y + activeview.Frame.Height + offset);

    // Calculate how far we need to scroll
    scroll_amount = (r.Height - (View.Frame.Size.Height - bottom)) ;

    // Perform the scrolling
    if (scroll_amount > 0) {
         moveViewUp = true;
         ScrollTheView (moveViewUp);
    } else {
         moveViewUp = false;
    }

}
```

The keyboard down event is simple.  If the View has been moved just reverse it.

```
private void KeyBoardDownNotification(NSNotification notification)
{
    if(moveViewUp){ScrollTheView(false);}
}
```

Scrolling the view will scroll the view in an animated manner.

```
private void ScrollTheView(bool move)
{

    // scroll the view up or down
    UIView.BeginAnimations (string.Empty, System.IntPtr.Zero);
    UIView.SetAnimationDuration (0.3);

    RectangleF frame = View.Frame;

    if (move) {
        frame.Y -= scrollamount;
    } else {
        frame.Y += scrollamount;
        scrollamount = 0;
    }

    View.Frame = frame;
    UIView.CommitAnimations();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I used your solution and ran into a problem. My calculated scroll_amount is always negative... Any Idea what I am doing wrong... Thx

Comment: @Christoph This post is from:  https://www.gooorack.com/2013/08/28/xamarin-moving-the-view-on-keyboard-show/  
Maybe will help you

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I'm using grid and stacks, wrap my root layout in a ScrollView, and set the orientation to neither. And it works without any Nuget and code-behind.
Actually, I tried the IQKeyboardManager, but none of it works, dependency deprecation.