# UIWebView Creates empty space below textfield when keyboard appears

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm using UIWebView in Xamarin iOS for loading my webpage

When the keyboard appears extra space appearing between textfield and keyboard, I need to remove the unwanted space, Kindly help on this. Thanks in Advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi , you need to share more explains about extra space , it will be helpful to check that .

Comment: I'm loading a login page using UIWebView in Xamarin iOS. When I'm start typing the user name the the view goes up and not able to see what we are typing.
Is their any way we can handle this from UIWebview deligates to control the css in webview

Comment: You can either fix it yourself or install a nuget package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130067/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-software-keyboard-is-shown-in-xamarin-ios